# Industrial moisturizers vs natural moisturizers?

Tags: dermatology, moisturize

There are a lot of brand names for industrial moisturizers: Cetaphil, Ceradan, Vaseline, etc. Also, for natural ones, there are a lot too: coconut oil, olive oil, honey, etc.

In my experience, natural oils are much cheaper and their effective is much longer, so I tend to use them. However, industrial moisturizers are less greasy. But it is nothing related to health.

What is the benefit of using industrial moisturizers over natural ones, and vice versa, when considering in health effect?

Comment: I voted to close. There are hundreds of natural moisturizers and hundreds of industrial moisturizers, and possibly a lot which fall in between (moisturizing mixtures produced by commercial entities in the organic branche). I doubt that there is a single health effect which all natural ones have in common but all industrial ones don't have, and vice versa. There is no way to make a meaningful comparison.

Comment: What if I don't count what fall in between?

Comment: I only mentioned the in-between ones to show you that the categories don't have a real definition. You'd need a criterion for deciding what's on one side, or the other, or in-between (it's more of a fluid spectrum). But that's less relevant. The main point is that even the ones on both sides have nothing in common, health-wise. There are more differences between the single products in each category than between the two categories. So there are no health related statements which can be made about the distinction of the two categories.

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. In your first comment: " I doubt that there is a single health effect which all natural ones have in common but all industrial ones don't have, and vice versa" ~> This is what I'm looking for. If it don't exist, just say it. It doesn't relate to the broadness of the question. In your second one: " the categories don't have a real definition" ~> no? For me, it's clear as crystal since we agree that the products fall in between are not be counted. Can you explain more?

Comment: I know of no crystal clear definition of "natural". What makes you put olive oil in the natural category and vaseline in the unnatural one, for example? And whatever this criterion is, is it applicable to all other examples you can come up with?

Comment: erm, Vaseline is cream, oilve oil is oil? Or you cannot product Vaseline without a factory?

Comment: Or how about put it in this way: long effect and cheap but greasy vs short effect and expensive but comfortable and convenient? I mean, there are a lot of ways to describe the categories.

Comment: but in case you really think that this question is too broad, I can change it to "What quality that a moisturizer need?"

Comment: I'm afraid the new category descriptions aren't better. The problem is that 1) any description of the categories you have in mind will be subjective, making it a bad SE question, and 2) the problem is not in the description, but that the categories you have chosen have no relation to the health effects. The new suggestion is also not really answerable, as what a moisturizer needs is to moisturize, and all of them do it. The side effects, positive and negative, differ wildly between all products you listed, and cannot be covered in a single question.

Comment: I understand your situation, I've frequently been confused what to buy in an array of products I know nothing about. And I know why you are looking for a simple principle to guide your buying decisions, but it simply doesn't exist where you're looking for it, especially when you have skin conditions which make your needs and constraints different from "standard" skin. Anongoodnurse has already answered some of your more focused question, and mentioned in one that she needed years to understand how skin care works. This alone suggests that this type of knowledge is awfully broad, but (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) this suggests a different avenue for you: if the topic interests you so much, why don't you build up the necessary knowledge, even if the volume is so high? Maybe try to catch anongoodnurse in chat and ask her for a good introductory book on the topic? Frankly, after the description of her expertise, I'm tempted to ask her if she has written it up in a book or a blog somewhere; I'd totally read it too.